# Python regex support for accents in NFKD Unicode when using `\w` expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, unicode-normalization

I'm trying to use Python 2.7's regular expression module to match all of the words in an NFKD normalized Unicode string. My understanding is that the `re.UNICODE` flag adds Unicode support to the `\w` expression, but I am not having any success with it.

```
>>> s = u'ca\u0308t'
>>> print s
cät
>>> pattern = re.compile(ur'\w+', flags=re.UNICODE)
>>> pattern.findall(s)
[u'ca', u't']
```

I suppose this is because `\u0308` is not considered alphanumeric, and so does not match with `\w`. The pattern matches with NFKC normalized Unicode:

```
>>> s
u'ca\u0308t'
>>> import unicodedata 
>>> r = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', s)
>>> pattern.findall(r)
[u'c\xe4t']
```

It would be nice if using `re.UNICODE` would make the parser consider `\u0061\u0308` equivalent to `\u00E4`. Is there anything I am doing wrong, or not aware of?

I will just use NFKC if nothing in the standard library can help. Thank you!

For information about Unicode normalization forms: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/

Edit: I just found that this question has been asked before: [Python regex \w doesn't match combining diacritics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141032/python-regex-w-doesnt-match-combining-diacritics?rq=1)

It looks like the best solution is to use [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) instead of `re`

Comment: Side note for clarity: In my code example I'm seeing the accent appear over the `t` in `cat`, but it should be appearing over the `a`, as in `ä`. While editing the post the accent appears over the `a`, there's something odd going on.

Comment: caU+0308t is matched by standard `\w` in Unicode mode. Where U+063U+0308 is considered one character.

Comment: Btw, why are you using an assignment as a parameter `flags=re.UNICODE` ? That might just return 1. Try it with just `re.UNICODE`

Comment: @sln in Python you can assign arguments to parameters explicitly. Here `flags` is the name of the parameter. I can use just `re.UNICODE` and have the same result. Regarding your first comment, that is the behavior I was expecting but not the behavior I observed.

Comment: I've tried this in boost and it works in Unicode mode. Have you tried the replacement engine `regex` instead of `re` ?

Comment: @sln Ah, I see. I am restricting myself to Python's standard library. For this project it is more convenient to use NFKC normalization than to add a dependency to my code.

Comment: @sln And now that I've looked at the `regex` package, it seems like a work around for this issue is generally unnecessary since `regex` is positioned to replace `re`. Maybe I should take it on as a dependency! Thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `\S+`

`\S` — All except whitespace

Exemple:

```
>>> re.compile(ur'\S+', flags=re.UNICODE).findall(u'ca\u0308t')
[u'ca\u0308t']
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately I am working with natural language and cannot assume white space is the perfect inverse of alphanumeric text. For example, from `¡cät!` I would like to capture only `cät`. In fact, I am trying to make someone else's code work with normalized Unicode. The expression giving me trouble is `re.compile(r'[\w\-\'_/&]+', re.UNICODE)`. So there is some punctuation I would like to capture, but most of it should be thrown away.