# Why doesn't the scikit learn tokenizer correctly tokenize utf-8 (portuguese) text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, scikit-learn

Here is some text, just two strings in a numpy ndarray:

```
titles
>>> array(['"a onda": como a psicologia social pode explicar a ação dos grupos?',
       '"beba menos mas beba melhor": entenda o lema da cerveja artesanal'],
      dtype=object)
```

I expected vectorizer within sklearn's `CountVectorizer` to correctly split the words but it doesn't seem to (note that it failed to tokenize the word "ação", it dropped the characters it couldn't understand):

```
cv=CountVectorizer()
cv.fit(titles)

tokenizer = cv.build_tokenizer()
[tokenizer(s) for s in titles]

[['onda',
  'como',
  'psicologia',
  'social',
  'pode',
  'explicar',
  'ac', ## <<<< sklearn failed to identify the word "ação"
  'dos',
  'grupos'],
 ['beba',
  'menos',
  'mas',
  'beba',
  'melhor',
  'entenda',
  'lema',
  'da',
  'cerveja',
  'artesanal']]
```

I'm using sklearn version **0.21.2** and Python version **3.6.7**.

Comment: It has a `token_pattern`, which is `(?u)\b\w\w+\b’`.https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the `?u` flag make `\w` match things like `ç` and `ã` already?

Comment: not combined diacritcs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3186313/67579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`CountVectorizer`** [scikit-doc]](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) uses a **`token_pattern`** parameter which is by default `(?u)\b\w\w+\b`.

Now `\w` unfortunately does [*not* capture combining diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3186313/67579). There *might* however be a workaround. We can pass the following regular expression instead:

```
cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'\b(?:[^\s]){2,}\b')
```

This seems to work for your given input:

```
>>> [tokenizer(s) for s in data]
[['onda',
  'como',
  'psicologia',
  'social',
  'pode',
  'explicar',
  'ação',
  'dos',
  'grupos'],
 ['beba',
  'menos',
  'mas',
  'beba',
  'melhor',
  'entenda',
  'lema',
  'da',
  'cerveja',
  'artesanal']]
```

But I am not very familiar with languages with a lot of diacritics to test if this works for all possible combining diacritics.

Comment: Alternatetively, you can use Unicode normalisation to composed form, eg. `import unicodedata as ud; ud.normalize('NFC', 'ação')` returns a string of length 4. It won't work for any imaginable combination of base char + diacritic, but regular Portuguese text should be fine.